# How to make TypeScript complain about non-matching function definitions in JSX props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make my TypeScript compiler (or at least vscode) warn about mismatching function definitions in JSX props.

I can have a React Component that has a prop defined as something like `onSomething: (value: boolean) => void` and then pass into that prop a function that defines no parameters. I know this is valid JS, but is there a way to get TS to warn about this usage?

[image: example]

In the above photo, the props wants a boolean parameter but the `onConfirmRebuild` defines zero parameters. TypeScript has no issue with that but I'd like it to.

### Edit

Below is the implementation of `onConfirmRebuild`. You can see it takes no params, but TS doesn't warn me or seem to care.

```
async function onConfirmRebuild() {
    // need only the selected collection names
    const collectionNames = gridData.filter((c) => c.selected).map((c) => c.name);

    // need only the selected box ids
    const boxIds = boxes
        .filter((b) => collectionNames.some((name) => name == b.collectionIdentifier))
        .map((box) => box.id);

    const success = await BoxAttributeApi.rebuild(auth, boxIds, false);

    setShowRebuildPrompt(false);

    if (success == false) {
        alert("Failed to submit attribute rebuild request");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm it should. Can you show your definition of `onConfirmRebuild`?

Comment: @Jayce444 sure, I added it to the original post ...

Comment: TypeScript always lets you use a function with less parameters than needed: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Comment: Yes, you're right, I think it's valid